# Can't generate sequence diagram in VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sequence-diagram

I don't see the Generate Sequence Diagram in VS when right clicking on/inside a method.  Does anyone know how to get that option back?

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/20/visual-studio-2010-generating-sequence-diagrams-on-the-fly.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio do you have?  I believe this option is only available to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.